# Apply event on dynamic Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generated the dynamic rows in table after 4 rows with a `Add New Item` button.

[image: Item_table]

with this code:

```
$('#add_more').click(function(e){
        var TTR = $('#items_data tbody tr');
        var HTML = '<tr>\n\
                        <td>'+ (TTR.length + 1)+'</td>\n\
                        <td><input type="text" style="width:450px;" name="item_name[]" value="" /></td>\n\
                        <td><input type="text" style="width:50px;" name="item_qty[]" value="1" /></td>\n\
                        <td><input type="text" style="width:100px;" name="item_price[]" /></td>\n\
                        <td></td>\n\
                        <td>\n\
                            <a href="#add"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n\
                            <a href="#del"><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></a>\n\
                        </td>\n\
                    </tr>';

        $(TTR.last()).after(HTML);
    });
```

So when i click on the `Add New Item` then the code generates the `Row 5` but the problem is my Event Handler on dynamic rows not working.

```
// This is working with Rest rows Not Dynamic
$('#items_data tr').on('keydown', 'td:eq(3) input', keyHandler);
```

But when i changed it to working for dynamic rows then it only works for single first row;

```
// This should works for dynamic rows as well but its 
// only work on the first row not the rest
$('#items_data').on('keydown', 'td:eq(3) input', keyHandler);
```

Comment: `$('#items_data').on('keydown', 'tr td:eq(3) input', keyHandler);`..

Comment: @Mr_Green i tried with this but its not working.

Comment: Try to use `input[name="item_price[]"]` as selector instead of `td:eq(3) input`. I imagine the `:eq(3)` doesn't really work for delegated event handlers, because there is only one element, not a set of elements.

Comment: @FelixKling you are right, the problem with `:eq(3)` now its working, please Add an answer so that it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that `:eq(3)` works (well) with delegated event handlers, because the selector is used to check whether the *given* element matches or not, not to *find* an element in a set of elements.

`:eq` is usually used to *reduce* a set of elements to a specific elements, e.g. to get the fourth element in a set. But in this case, there is no set to get an element from, or rather, the set only contains *one* element, the one that triggered the event.

Use another selector, such as `input[name="item_price[]"]` or `td:nth-child(4) input`. `:nth-child` works, as opposed to `:eq`, because it explicitly means "match if the element is the n-th child of its parent".

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 $('#items_data tbody').on('keydown', 'tr td:eq(3) input', keyHandler);
```

Reason : your row is also dynamically generated so you cannot pass it has selector like `$('#items_data tr')`.

Comment: That's what the OP tried: `$('#items_data').on('keydown', 'td:eq(3) input', keyHandler);`.

Comment: Why do you think `#items_data tbody` would work and `#items_data` wouldn't?